# Equivalent formula - how do I go from $\neg (P \wedge \neg Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q)$ to $\neg P \vee Q$?

Tags: logic

This is item "c" of question 11 from section 1.2 in Daniel J. Velleman's "How to Prove It - A Structured Approach" (great book).

The question asks that I find a simpler formula equivalent to $\neg (P \wedge \neg Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q)$, and the answer at the end of the book is $\neg P \vee Q$.  I've tried DeMorgan and the associative and commutative laws, to no avail. I'm at my wit's end. All I got was $(\neg P \vee Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q)$.

Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried one of the two distributive laws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\neg (P \wedge \neg Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q)$

(de Morgan's)

$(\neg P \lor Q) \lor (\neg P \land Q)$

(distributivity; associativity)

$(\neg P \lor Q \lor \neg P) \land (\neg P \lor Q \lor Q)$

Should be easy to see from here.

Comment: Great, and now I see I overlooked the idempotent law. Thanks!

Comment: @Georger Make sure to understand Alex Becker's answer as well.

Comment: I understand. It's just that the point of the question is to find a simpler equivalent formula using solely the laws.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $(\neg P \wedge Q)$ holds then $(\neg P \vee Q)$ holds, so $(\neg P \vee Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q)\iff (\neg P \vee Q)$.

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative approach you can make the **truth table** of both logical expressions.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c| c|c| c|c| c|c| c|}
\hline
P                         & Q                   & 
\neg P                    &  \neg Q             &
\neg (P \wedge \neg Q)    & (\neg P \wedge Q)   & 
\neg (P \wedge \neg Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q)
\\\hline
V                         & V                   & 
F                         & F                   &
V                         & F                   & 
V
\\\hline
V                         & F                   & 
F                         & V                   &
F                         & F                   & 
F
\\\hline
F                         & V                   & 
V                         & F                   &
V                         & V                   &
V 
\\\hline
F                         & F                   & 
V                         & V                   &
V                         & F                   & 
V
\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
and
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c| c|c|}
\hline
 P&Q&\neg P& \neg P \vee Q 
\\\hline
 V&V&F& V 
\\\hline
 V&F&F& F 
\\\hline
 F&V&V& V 
\\\hline
 F&F&V& V 
\\\hline
\end{array}
$$